# Groovy parser: add node with special namespace

Tags: parsing, groovy, namespaces

I'm working with groovy xmlParser.
I have a source xml which I need to transform partly to get a slightly different target xml.
In the target xml I need to add a node (which I already managed so far) with:

ParentNode.appendNode('ChildNode', [: ], StringValue)

The outcome is:
`<ChildNode>Text</ChildNode>`

But what I need is this:

```
<n1:ChildNode xmlns:n1="http://any_namespace">Text</n1:ChildNode>
```

Can anybody give a hint here?
When I try to add the namespace somehow in the brackets for the function, the error comes up in the next statement:

String newBody = XmlUtil.serialize(root);

It says that the namespace n1 is not defined.

Thanks a lot!
BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the namespace as an attribute:

```
ParentNode.appendNode('n1:ChildNode', ['xmlns:n1': 'http://any_namespace'], stringValue)
```